# How to name a programmatically created VPN on AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Looking at the [AWS SDK v3 createVpc() documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#createvpc) there's not a way for me to specify a name for my VPN.  Is there another way to do this so that the AWS GUI still makes sense?  We intend to only use the API for initial setup, not maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your VPC using the `createVpc()` method, you'll get your VPC ID in the response.

Use the `createTags()` method to add the "Name" tag to your VPC specifying the VPC ID in the `createTags()` call.